# .htaccess and reverse proxy not redirecting correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website which consists in 2 sections (each on separate server): main site and a blog part.

I have successfully managed to configure reverse proxy and the blog section to be placed under https://example.com/blog, but not all addresses are redirected correctly at it should.

Right now, I have correctly redirected the following urls:

http{s}://www.domain to https: //domain/
http{s}://blog.domain to https:// domain/blog

The issue is that if I will enter an URL like https:// domain/blog/an-article the redirection fails (the URL is not rewritten). Also, it fails for an URL like https://www. domain/blog/////an-article.

My .htaccess files are:
Main site .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Blog .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /blog/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Happy to give you more details if required.
Thank you!

Comment: How is `http{s}://blog.domain` being redirected?

Comment: http:// goes to https:// domain/blog while https:// sends a 404

Comment: Yes, but __how__? There is no rule above for that redirection

Comment: in virtual host file ProxyPass       /blog/  http://blog.domain/
ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://blog.domain/